# Visualize 3D data to wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visualization

I have a `double Points[x,3] array` that contains `x,y,z coordinates` of a human point cloud and I want to visualize the data.

I am using `using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;` but i can't convert `double` to `Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D`.

How do I visualize the data?

Comment: you need to provide code of what you have tried or you'll receive downvotes instead of help

Comment: what do you mean by visualize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Linq:

```
IEnumerable<Point3D> points = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length(0))
              .Select(i => new Point3D(array[i,0],
                                       array[i,1],
                                       array[i,2]));
```